# Javascript form calculations return NaN until last entry

Tags: javascript, forms, calculator, nan

JavaScript newbie.

I'm trying to create a simple calculator with displayed values that dynamically update as the user enters more info. My problem: The "rate" displayed in the green circle always displays as "NaN" until the user enters the final form value (all the values).

I tried using .value, parseFloat, etc. I'd be grateful for any suggestions or corrections--I know the JS isn't very elegant (and not working well, either).

JSFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/thinkhuman/8ftuw/

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: **A poster solved the NaN problem below, but the other half of the problem is: the "rate" value (in the green cirlce) doesn't update when the associated_costs and nonbillable values change. Any advice on that part?**

```
<!--Web page for the JS app-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>What's My Rate?</title>
<!--   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 -->  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="title">
<h1>What's My Rate?</h1>
<h3>Calculate your real-world freelance rate for web design/development.</h3>
</div>

<div class="calcwrapper">

    <div class="entries">

        <label for="targetsalary">Target salary (yearly):</label>
        <input type="text" id="target_salary" name="targetsalary" onchange="calculate();">
<br />
        <label for="associatedcosts">Associated costs (%):</label>
        <input type="text" id="associated_costs" name="associatedcosts" onchange="calculate();">
<br />

        <label for="timeoff">Time off (hours/year):</label>
        <input type="text" id="timeoff" name="timeoff" onchange="calculate();">
<br />          
        <label for="nonbillable">Non-billable time (%):</label>
        <input type="text" id="nonbillable" name="nonbillable" onchange="calculate();">
<br />
        <label for="profit">Desired profit (%):</label>
        <input type="text" id="profit" name="profit" onchange="calculate();">

    </div>

    <div class="ratedisplay">
           <p class="rate" id="required_rate"></p>
           <p class="ratesubtitle">per hour</p>
    </div> 

<div class="moreinfo">
<p>For a detailed explanation of why calculating your real-world rate is critical, see <a href="http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/calculate-hourly-freelance-rates-web-design-development-work" target="_blank"> Neil Tortorella's excellent blog post </a> on Teamtreehouse.com.</p>
</div>

</div>



<script src="whatsmyrate.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
/*  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
*/  color: #384047;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.calcwrapper{
    max-width: 700px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    background: #f4f7f8;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.entries{
    max-width: 400px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    float:left;
}

.ratedisplay{

    background-color: #5fcf80;
    float: right;
    color: #fff;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 4.0em;
    border: 1px solid #3ac162;
    margin-right: 150px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 -5px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1) inset;
}

.ratesubtitle{

    font-size: 0.4em;
    color: black;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.rate{

    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}



.title{

    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

input{
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    max-width: 100px;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: auto;
/*  margin: 0;
*/  outline: 0;
    background-color: #e8eeef;
    color: #8a97a0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.02) inset;
}



.moreinfo{
    display:inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

label{
display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: right;}
```

...aaaand the JavaScript:

```
//A tool for calculating your real-world hourly rate for web design/development work. 

/***************
PROCESS OVERVIEW
****************/
//1. Specify target_salary.
//2. Specify associated_costs %.
//3. Calculate new target_salary (target_salary + associated_costs).
//4. Specify time_off (holidays, vacation, sick days), and subtract from total_yearly_hours.
//5. Specify non-billable time, subtract from total hours.
//6. Calculate overhead % ((hourly_rate * overhead)+ hourly_rate)
//7. Specify profit %, and add to hourly_rate

/*********
VARIABLES
**********/
//target_salary
//associated_costs(%)
//total_required_salary = target_salary + associated_costs
//time_off = 176 hours (holidays 56, vacation 80 , sick days 40)
//non_billable_time = 25%
//overhead_costs(%)
//profit
//total_yearly_hours = 2080
//billable_hours = total_yearly_hours - (time_off + non_billable_time)
//required_rate = total_required_salary / billable_hours

//document.getElementById("required_rate").style.display='none';

function calculate() {

    var total_yearly_hours = 2080;

    // Get values for ALL elements on screen
    var target_salary    = document.getElementById("target_salary");
    var associated_costs = document.getElementById("associated_costs");
    var timeoff          = document.getElementById("timeoff");
    var nonbillable      = document.getElementById("nonbillable");
    var profit           = document.getElementById("profit");
    var required_rate    = document.getElementById("required_rate");

    // Get the user's input from the input elements. 
    var salary    = parseFloat(target_salary.value);
    var costs     = parseFloat(associated_costs.value) / 100;
    var vacation  = parseFloat(timeoff.value);
    var freehours = parseFloat(nonbillable.value);
    var extra     = parseFloat(profit.value) / 100;

    // Compute the total required salary and billable hours.
    var total_salary = (salary * (costs / 100)) + salary;
    var billable_hours = total_yearly_hours - ((freehours/100)+vacation);
    var rate = "$" + Math.floor(((total_salary * extra) + total_salary) /  billable_hours);

//rate = total salary + profit, / billable hours.

    // If the result is a finite number, the user's input was good 
    if (isNaN(rate)) {
        required_rate.innerHTML = rate;
    }
    else{
        required_rate.innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Isolate the problem you're having, don't slap all of your code into the question.

Comment: Good point. I just wasn't sure what was helpful to see, so since the code's short, I posted it all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your condition you're getting a string, `$NaN` as you're doing

```
var rate = "$" + Math.floor(((total_sala ...
```

see how you add the dollarsign making it a string, and that's not NaN, it's a string

Remove the dollarsign

```
var rate = Math.floor(((total_sala ...
```

then do (note the condition is the wrong way around in your code)

```
if (isNaN(rate)) {
    required_rate.innerHTML = "";
} else {
    required_rate.innerHTML = '$' + rate;
}
```

comparing the actual number in the condition, and then adding the dollarsign

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/SXsV2/1/)

Comment: Thank you! That works, and solves the NaN problem. I just realized the other half of the problem is: when a user updates a value, it's not updating the "rate" value dynamically in the interface. At all.

Comment: Seems to do that for me, when I change  one of the values, the number in the green circle  changes ?

Comment: Sorry, to be specific, the number in the green circle doesn't update when the associated_costs and nonbillable values are changed. The other three do cause updates.

Comment: Strange; not for me, even when using your Fiddle. I tried in Chrome and Firefox. It's the second and fourth fields I'm talking about.

Comment: @James - Yes, when I change those the total value changes as well, I just keep adding numbers and it changes eventually ?

Comment: Ah well. Thanks for solving my NaN problem! Marking your answer as best.